# Unable to install java 8 on Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu-14.04

I used the following code to add repository,

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Then I have updated the packages using `sudo apt-get update`, After this when I try to install Java using the following command,

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

I am getting error, the error code response is,

2016-04-20 13:00:45 (442 MB/s) - ‘jdk-8u77-linux-i586.tar.gz’ saved [5165]

```
Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-8u77-linux-i586.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to debug and resolve this, I am new to Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Is there any option in stackverflow.com where i can directly move questions between forums (to askubuntu.com), please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to install JDK:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Thanks,